# Hide T-SQL Results and Only show RowCount

Tags: t-sql

I have a query and just want the rowcount to show up, not the results from the proc I'm calling.

For example this:

```
exec GetSomething
    @UserID = 112233,
    @MaxAge = 50,
    ... etc.

SET @Count = @@rowcount
SELECT @Count
```

returns not only the count but also the first recordset's list of resulting records before the count is selected.

How can I still do this count but not show the recordset results?

Comment: change the query to do a count(*) instead of returning rows? Returning rows you'll never use is a waste of resources.

Comment: I like using rowcount.  The RowCount is not the problem.  I just need to damper the results from the proc so it doesn't show up in the query analyzer results but still let Select SELECT @ Count show the value it's currently showing.  I just want to see the SELECT @Count result only, not the records that go along with it which is produced by the call of the proc before it.

Comment: I just prefer the syntax is all over Count(*).  I don't get what you are so huffy about. all I said was "rowcount works fine"...and what you mean, rowcount is returning the right count...plus I explained myself and then you just blew up?  wtf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Something TABLE (
   ...
)

INSERT INTO @Something
EXECUTE GetSomething
   @UserID = 112233,
   @MaxAge = 50,
   ... etc.;

SET @Count = @@rowcount
SELECT @Count
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try using OPENROWSET but you have to make sure it's enabled:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=(local)\SQL2008;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
     'EXEC GetSomething')
```

To enabled OPENROWSET:

```
sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

See MSDN on OPENROWSET:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx

Comment: If your goal is to run the query, then run @@rowcount, then to my knowledge there is no way to hide the results.